# JsGrid sum two (database) fields and show result in grid

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsgrid

I have a jsGrid which is build by using a JSON result from a database query.
The database returns the fields Amount1 and Amount2 (for example).

I want to sum those to fields to create a new field which will be shown in the grid. Something like:

```
   fields: [{
               name: "Amount1",
               type: "text",
               title: "bla",
               width: 45
           },
           {
               name: "Amount2",
               type: "text",
               title: "blabla",
               width: 60 
           },
           {
               name: "Sum",
               type: "text"
           }, 
           {
               itemTemplate: function(Sum) {
                   return Amount1.value + Amount2.value {
                       someformatting
                   };
               },
```

How can I Achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I Achieve that?

Inside of [`itemTemplate`](http://js-grid.com/docs/#fields) function there is two parameter `value` and  `item`.

- **itemTemplate** is a function to create cell content. It should return markup as string, DomNode or jQueryElement. The function signature is <kbd>function(value, item)</kbd>, where <kbd>value</kbd> is a value of column property of data item, and <kbd>item</kbd> is a row data item.

You can get your sum value using `item.Amount1+item.Amount2`

**DEMO**

```js
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
  width: "100%",
  
  data: [{
    Amount1: 10,
    Amount2: 12
  }, {
    Amount1: 156,
    Amount2: 125
  }, {
    Amount1: 101,
    Amount2: 122
  }],
  fields: [{
    width: 80,
    align:'center',
    name: "Amount1",
    type: "number"
  }, {
    width: 80,
    align:'center',
    name: "Amount2",
    type: "number",
  }, {
    width: 80,
    align:'center',
    headerTemplate: function() {
      return "<th class='jsgrid-header-cell'>Sum</th>";
    },
    itemTemplate: function(value, item) {
      return item.Amount1+item.Amount2;
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>

<div id="jsGrid"></div>
```